# Implementing Benders decomposition for MILP

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to implement a Benders decomposition on MILP. But I cannot understand a notation in the sub-problem constraints.
What does ":" mean in the following sub-problem? The implementation works except for the dual variable which I don't know where should I put it.
$$
minimize \quad  \mathcal z_{s_1}=-\frac{3}{2}y_1-2y_2+40w\\
-y_1-3y_2+2x-w\le2\\
y_1+3y_2-x-w\le3\\
x= 100 :\lambda_1\\
y_1,y_2\ge 0\\
y_1,y_2 \in  R
$$
I used pulp to implement it but the ":" in constraint $x= 100 :\lambda_1$ confused me.

It is the computational example 6.2 in Decomposition technique book by Antonio J. Conejo on page 246.

Thank you.

Comment: May be this means $\lambda_1$ is the dual of constraint $x=100$.

Comment: Thanks Ervin. Yes, you are right. I am a bit newbie to optimization and duality world. To anyone who has the same problem: you can recover constraints dual variable in pulp as instructed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606094/how-to-show-the-dual-of-a-primal-linear-program-defined-in-pulp. In GAMS it is the MARGINAL value associated to a constraint.